# Copying in arguments to a function pointer

Tags: c, function, pointers

A [nice tutorial on function pointers](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/function-pointers.html) is giving an example I have a questions on. It's a simple sorting function that has a function as one of its arguments. Here is the function call. As you can see there are two "const void*" arguements to the (*compar) function

```
void qsort(void *base, size_t nmemb, size_t size,
        int(*compar)(const void *, const void *));
```

Later on this function is called:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int int_sorter( const void *first_arg, const void *second_arg )
{
    int first = *(int*)first_arg;
    int second = *(int*)second_arg;
    if ( first < second )
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else if ( first == second )
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return 1;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int array[10];
    int i;
    /* fill array */
    for ( i = 0; i < 10; ++i )
    {
        array[ i ] = 10 - i;
    }
    qsort( array, 10 , sizeof( int ), int_sorter );
    for ( i = 0; i < 10; ++i )
    {
        printf ( "%d\n" ,array[ i ] );
    }

}
```

My question is how does the compiler know which two elements the "int_sorter" is comparing? They are not called out in the initial function and I think that is because the function called as an argument handles that but how does *that* function know that within this array we are comparing *these* two numbers?

I'm also not sure what `*(int *)` means; I suspect that is part of the answer.

Comment: `*(int *)p` means cast `p` to `int*`, then indirect to get the `int` pointed to. The rest of your question is rather fuzzy.

Comment: Why do yo suppose you gave `qsort()` both an item count, *and* an item size? And do you have an idea how *memory* is occupied by variables in C?

Comment: Could you point me to the URL of the tutorial you are talking about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `qsort()` function is responsible for (repeatedly) calling the comparator function with the correct two pointers.  They are pointers to two elements of the array that was passed to `qsort()`.  The compiler has no clue about which two elements `int_sorter()` is comparing.

The `first = *(int *)first_arg;` notation converts the `const void *` into an `int *`, then dereferences the `int` (reading it, thus not violating the `const` constraint), and assigning the value to `first`.  The `const void *` arguments say "the comparator function should not modify the data pointed at by the pointer arguments".

The design of `qsort()` allows it to sort arrays of any type; the information it needs is all present in the interface.

Answer (score 2):

> My question is how does the compiler know which to elements the
>   "int_sorter" is comparing? They are not called out in the initial function 
>   and I think that is because the function called as an argument handles that

Yes, exactly. The `qsort()` function uses the function pointer you gave it (the pointer to `int_sorter`) to call the function `int_sorter`. It will typically call `int_sorter` many times, each time with different elements from the array to be sorted.

> but how does that function know that within this array we are
>   comparing these two numbers?

Again, the function on its own does not know. The `qsort()` function decides which numbers it must compare, and then compares them.

It will probably help if you look at a simple implementation of a sort function, so you can see the actual function calls.

> I'm also not sure what *(int *) means

As explained in the other answer: `(int*)` means "cast this to a 'pointer to int'". The star in front is the dereferencing operator (to go from pointer to value).

Comment: Here is the site http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/function-pointers.html

Comment: @WilliamDussault: If you want to provide more information, it's better to edit it into the question. I did this for you this time.